# How to return binary data from AWS Lambda written in Java

Tags: java, excel, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, binaryfiles

Given that it is now possible to handle binary data in Amazon Api Gateway and [Amazon Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-programming-model-req-resp.html#java-handler-io-type-stream), I wanted to try to make an Amazon Lambda endpoint which returned an Excel spreadsheet. It is entirely possible to do so using node/js, as demonstrated [here](https://github.com/krisgholson/serverless-thumbnail). Unfortunately, any time I try to do this using Java, it falls to pieces.

My initial attempt was to create a simple workbook using apache XSSFWorkbook, write it to the output stream provided by RequestStreamHandler, and done.

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestStreamHandler;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class FileRequestHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context)
            throws IOException {
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        String sheetName = "Problem sheet";
        wb.createSheet(sheetName);
        wb.write(outputStream);
    }
}
```

When tested locally, the output stream can be piped to a file resulting in a valid output excel file.

```
import com.amazonaws.util.StringInputStream;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class FileRequestHandlerTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldCreateExcelFile() throws IOException {
        FileRequestHandler fileRequestHandler = new FileRequestHandler();
        InputStream inputStream = new StringInputStream("hello world");
        String fileName = "FileRequestLambda";
        String path = fileName + ".xlsx";
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(path);

        fileRequestHandler.handleRequest(inputStream, fileOutputStream, TestUtils.createContext());
        fileOutputStream.close();
    }
}
```

But when I run it in Amazon Lambda, I get malformed binary output:

```
PKn��I_rels/.rels���j�0��}
�{㴃1F�^Ơ�2��l%1I,c�[��3�l
l�����H��4��R�l��·����q}*�2�������;�*��
t"�^�l;1W)�N�iD)ejuD�cKz[׷:}g����@:�
�3����4�7N�s_ni�G�M*7�����2R�+��    �2�/�����b��mC�Pp�ֱ$POyQ�抒�DsZ��IС�'un���~�PK����OPKn��I[Content_Types].xml�SMO1��+6��m��1���G%��β
�J[���MDL0�S;yo�{3i�Ӎ5�c��5lć�B'��nѰ��S}˪��)0�aÜg��`<�L��԰.�p'D�ZH�t��>Z�Tƅ ��@q=��]F��\4�=`+���P�!-!S.�v�@��+�����N�tEV=nHe7���S,;K]_h7Q+�W8߶Z��re��c�U�����}�����g�&A��,���H�$�B<��`�"�Jb���"���I�N�1���A���CI�#��܂v��?|\�{��`�b������$�c�D��|2�PKKB�>'PKn��IdocProps/app.xmlM��
�0D�~EȽ��ADҔ���A? ��6�lB�J?ߜ���0���ͯ��)�@��׍H6���V>��$;�SC
;̢(�ra�g�l�&�e��L!y�%��49��`_���4G���F��J��Wg
�GS�b����
~�PK�|wؑ�PKn��IdocProps/core.xmlm��J�0F��!�m�V����(���Ż��m��!�v}{ӺVP/g��a��wG5�wp~4��4�1-�u���n��c�גOFC����6��e�888c��<�홰
B��/P�g��q�b��!��'��W�)��"
�<p�S��I)Ŧ�onZR�@��Ќ�6�S�߅u��G?n�<��\�\����ۛ���t���p|��f� Q4��ac&ߓ��������i��"�UG+vV��z�ɯ���U�^�H@�����IM�$�&�PK����PKn��Ixl/sharedStrings.xml=�A� ﾂ��.z0Ɣ�`������,�����q2��o�ԇ���N�E��x5�z>�W���(R�K���^4{�����ŀ�5��y�V����y�m�XV�\�.��j�����
8�PKp��&x�PKn��I
xl/styles.xml���n� ��>bop2TQ��P)U��RWb�6*�����ӤS�Nw�s���3ߍ֐���t��(l��������ҝx�!N=@$ɀ��}��3c���ʰr`:i��2��w,�
�d
�T��R#�voc �;c�iE���Û��E<|��4Iɣ�����F#��n���B�z�F���y�j3y��yҥ�jt>���2��Lژ�!6��2F��OY��4@M�!���G��������1�t��y��p��" n����u�����a�ΦDi�9�&#��%I��9��}���cK��T��$?������`J������7���o��f��M|PK�1X@C�PKn��Ixl/workbook.xml���N�0��<��wj�E�8��J��P�;�����hmZ'Q�#����~;���;vCJ6   �Fà���"��|x|�}���#]����C�0�<֜'=�WiG��#y���O#�2i@������+`!��F�{��-�O�!/B�r)�;&h�����zOz�o����xO��I2����YuĔ��s�u��<J8Q�z6��Qm�:�,�c��Z�����PK1����dPKn��Ixl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels��Mk1@���0�nv-�R�^����0$����$dƯo���R�OC�ރ�-��������@Sՠ(�����ܼ?��b��p�����d�AJ�¾O�
#�/�޴f�iD�b�P6m�#Jy�N'�[�HO��E�k����3�W���ܑ`���Zri㪐����?�ض��e�������7p�wj�W5r���]������=�|���<:�[p��7�O�PK��4��9PKn��Ixl/worksheets/sheet1.xmleP�N�0���މ�V��THU$���$��j���[��c�����3��-v�nT���/a����7�Zߗ��z���]uQ���0 ��zJD�[�C3�3!�    }|鈝�H��ab4�br�^���v�z���:�)P1v%ܭ@W�"|�8�?X�ܚ���C[B�'�~��ȅO������Tyb�bgN�<�|��$��ƙ��{#&����h��>��D�Ű�z�#��6��8�LF�dQ����,4�xS����/PK�_�Y�lPKn��I����O_rels/.relsPKn��IKB�>'[Content_Types].xmlPKn��I�|wؑ��docProps/app.xmlPKn��I����mdocProps/core.xmlPKn��Ip��&x��xl/sharedStrings.xmlPKn��I�1X@C�
nxl/styles.xmlPKn��I1����d�xl/workbook.xmlPKn��I��4��9xl/_rels/workbook.xml.relsPKn��I�_�Y�l$   xl/worksheets/sheet1.xmlPK      ?Z
```

The output is about 5KB in size, while the output on my local computer is about 3KB in size. This appears to be a problem with binary output in general for Java on Amazon Lambda. When I do run some code that writes an image to the output string, it also works locally, but results in an image twice the size and garbled when run from Amazon Lambda.

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestStreamHandler;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class ImageRequestHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context)
            throws IOException {
        String address = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1d/AmazonWebservices_Logo.svg/580px-AmazonWebservices_Logo.svg.png";
        URL url = new URL(address);

        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int n;
        while (-1!=(n=in.read(buf)))
        {
            out.write(buf, 0, n);
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        byte[] response = out.toByteArray();
        outputStream.write(response);
    }
}
```

The types of the was input and output streams are:

lambdainternal.util.NativeMemoryAsInputStream
lambdainternal.util.LambdaByteArrayOutputStream

Help?

Comment: Consider whether you really want to push the entire excel file through the result of your lambda.  Might it make more sense to stage it on s3 and return a presigned URL?  This would handle excel files of "any size" - [lambda response payload can apparently only be 6M](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html)  This will also keep your lambda executions short ( writing to S3 is going to be pretty reliable and very fast) and leave the data transfer in the hands of S3 which is very good at it.  You can also download the file again in case of failure without another invoke.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with returning JPG image from Amazon Lambda and I found a work-around.
You need to encode an output stream with base64 encoding:

```
OutputStream encodedStream = Base64.getEncoder().wrap(outputStream);
encodedStream.write(response);
encodedStream.close();
```

Then you need to update Method Response and Integration Response of your function as described here: [AWS Gateway API base64Decode produces garbled binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41429551/aws-gateway-api-base64decode-produces-garbled-binary/41434295#41434295)