# How do I send a binary response with AWS Lambda with API Gateway in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to set up a Lambda and API Gateway that will do a s3.getObject() and output the binary image as a response. Eventually I'd like to pull an image from s3 and resize on the fly instead of saving them back to s3, however I can't seem to get even a simple image to output.

My simple lambda looks like this:

```
'use strict';

const http = require('http');    

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    http.get('https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIFN0.jpg', function(res) {
        var body = '';
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            // Agregates chunks
            body += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            callback(null, body);
        });
    });    
};
```

I've set the API Gateway Binary Support to allow 'image/jpeg' and I've tried setting the Content Type in the Method Response and Integration Response.

**Method Response:**
[image]

**Integration Response:**
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found my answer here: [AWS Gateway API base64Decode produces garbled binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41429551/aws-gateway-api-base64decode-produces-garbled-binary/41434295?noredirect=1#comment70201737_41434295)

It requires a CLI command to change a setting that isn't exposed in the AWS Console when you select Lambda Function on the Create Method screen.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read this [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/binary-support-for-api-integrations-with-amazon-api-gateway/)?

Please follow those instructions and ensure your client is correctly sending the Content-Type and Accept headers

Comment: That blog post example is for a binary upload which I've done successfully but I haven't been able to display a binary image through a lamba. 

There is also this article but it doesn't use a lambda.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html

Comment: The blog post demonstrates a binary response of a thumbnail image from API Gateway/Lambda, which I think is very similar to what you are trying to do.