# How to upload audio file to s3 via api gateway?

Tags: audio, amazon-s3, request, multipartform-data, aws-api-gateway

I created an API in API Gateway to upload audio files to s3, the file is sending from local PC as multipart/form-data.

API integration request is shown below

[image: api integration request is shown below]

In URL Path Parameters, added bucket as param and directly added the bucket name

[image]

When I try to upload the file I get an error response,

```js
body: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>x-amz-content-sha256 must be UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD, STREAMING-AWS4-HMAC-SHA256-PAYLOAD, or a valid sha256 value.</Message><ArgumentName>x-amz-content-sha256</ArgumentName><ArgumentValue>null</ArgumentValue><RequestId>123445667788</RequestId><HostId>abcd/Jefgh2272vb/ghvsvds+gh+6273gdhsg+gdgshdshdsjdsj=</HostId></Error>'
```

What are the changes need to be done?

Comment: Hi,
Can you add the answer about what you did to solve this and mark this as answered? It'll help other people with the same issue.

Comment: Please go through the edits in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found some very useful document

[please go through this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings.html) if you also face the same probem!!

added multipart/form-data to binary support in api.