# How to use AWS Lambda to fetch a webpage and return body and headers

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, node-fetch

I am trying to use Lambda functions to fetch a webpage, and then return both the content and the response headers. Following is my code which always return "Internal server error" when triggered by Gateway API, I am confused with how to construct the `response` object, it dose not seem to have any document about it. Any hit is highly appreciated!

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    let r = await fetch('http://www.google.com');
    let buffer = await r.buffer();
    const response = {
        statusCode: r.status,
        body: buffer,
        header: r.headers
    };

    return response;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you are using the `response.buffer()` method. What you should be using here is the `response.text()` method. It will return the response body in plain text. And since the headers you are getting from the response already include the `Content-Type: text/html` header, you should be able to return a html document.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Changing it to text() does return a HTML doc, but I meant to return content types not only limited to text/html. I found there is something wrong with the line ```header: r.headers```  since the returned response does not include any header returned from the fetch.

Comment: Okay, I see. It might be that the header values returned from `response.headers` are arrays. If you only need the `content-type` header, you could use `response.headers.get("content-type")`.

Comment: Well, with further testing, it seems that I am not able to put ```buffer``` as the value of ```body```, whenever I do it, it return Internal server error, wonder if you also know the reason by any chance. thanks!

Comment: I found it myself, it seems I have to return strings anyway, but can command the API Gateway to treat data as binary: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45348580/aws-lambda-fails-to-return-pdf-file