# How to prevent api gateway from converting base64 response

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a service that returns image data as base64 encoded text in the body:e.g.

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAAEsCAYAAAB5fY51AAAgAE...etc
```

However, when we put the service behind the api-gateway behaving as a proxy, the same request will seemingly convert the response to binary

```
�PNG


IHDR,,y}�u IDA... etc
```

and has a response header

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

The documentation explains how to convert TO binary automatically, but makes no mention on how to leave the response unmodified. I've tried changing contentHandling to CONVERT_TO_TEXT with no success, so I'm wondering if there's another way of having the api gateway not mess with my service responses.

Comment: Your backend is **not** a Lambda function... correct?  Is this an HTTP proxy integration?

Comment: Correct. Using proxy integration.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the same setup as me;

```
API gateway 
  V      
Proxy (no contentHandling available)    
  V
Lambda (returns {body: Buffer.toString('base64')})
```

This solved it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47780921/853015.