# how i can get a image.png o jpg? in apigateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

i use apigateway and i call some images or documents like **(svg, png, jpg, pdf)**
but also i cant get **jpg** or **png** images and my configuration is this:

[image: Method Response]

[image: Integration Response]

and when i call my api , apigateway return
[image: response]

but if i change the Content handling to **Passthrough**
this retrurn

[image: other response]

so i want to know if i make something wrong, i have read this example *[AWS API Gateway base64Decode produces garbled binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41429551/aws-api-gateway-base64decode-produces-garbled-binary/41434295#41434295)*

Comment: Did you solve the issue?