# Quarkus API Gateway lambda integration forcing base64 encoded response

Tags: aws-api-gateway, quarkus

I have a Quarkus REST-endpoint (quarkus-amazon-lambda-rest) that serves content from a S3 bucket. I push the Response as raw bytes with the correct content type but the client gets base64-encoded data which if course results in failure to display the image or whatever.

Is there some way of disabling this functionality so that it would pass through API Gateway as-is? I have added image/png to the binary media types but still no go

Or perhaps this question could be more generic "what would make a API Gateway (REST) ignore the content-type/binary media type integration from a proxy lambda"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47780921/175554 may help

Comment: Thanks, the post referred another post that suggested */* for binary media types and that actually works! (also for JSON etc)